# Ширина и высота ячеек в bootstrap

Tags: bootstrap

```
            <table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Фамилия</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td>1</td>
                            <td>2</td>
                            <td>3</td>
                            <td>4</td>
                            <td>5</td>
                            <td>6</td>
                            <td>7</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
```

Как задать ширину и высоту всех ячеек td 30px ?

Comment: `table td { width: 30px; height: 30px; }`, не?

Comment: нет, размер не меняется

Answer (score 1):

Так?

```css
table td,
table th {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

table {
  word-break: break-all;
}
```

```html
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Фамилия</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>4</td>
            <td>5</td>
            <td>6</td>
            <td>7</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```